# Can I use Spring AOP on CommandLineRunner

Tags: java, spring

I have this simple spring boot project

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

The main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class BatchApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BatchApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use Spring AOP, I have this Aspect Class

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class BatchAspect {

    @Before(value = "execution(* com.example.demo.Test.*(..))")
    public void beforeAdvice(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        System.out.println("Before method:" + joinPoint.getSignature());
    }
    @After(value = "execution(* com.example.demo.Test.*(..))")
    public void afterAdvice(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        System.out.println("After method:" + joinPoint.getSignature());
    }
}
```

and this CommandLineRunner

```
package com.example.demo;

@Component
public class AopCommandLineRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private Test test;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        test.test();
    }
}
```

and the Test class

```
package com.example.demo;

@Component
public class Test {
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("RUN");
    }
}
```

When application run, methods beforeAdvice and afterAdvice are never called
What am i missing?

Comment: And they should because? The pointcut matches nothing.

Comment: Please add the package declarations to your classes and the fulll `CommandLineRunner` (is it an inlined class, a top level calss etc).

Comment: question updated

Comment: please confirm if the Aspect is autodetected . Do share the packages of the `BatchApplication` and `BatchAspect` as well

Comment: Not updated enough, you left out the important package declartion on the aspect and application class (those are the ones I'm interested in).

Comment: they have the same package com.example.demo

Comment: This code works for me.Is this the complete `pom.xml` ? Could you please share the imports for `BatchAspect`?

Comment: I found the problem, when I created the BatchAspect class with IntelliJ, I created a file with the extension .aj. Sorry and thanks for the help